# what is the difference between JSON-WSP and JSON Restful api?

Tags: json, rest

I have a client who want to build an mobile app and he said using JSON-WSP
I was wondering is the same as normal JSON Api?

Comment: I have used the OpenAPI specificiation since I integrate Swagger (https://swagger.io/specification/).  Swagger is great tool to self document APIs and allow end users to test out the API.  In regards to your question, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546500/json-wsp-or-json-rpc/7548918 for  more details.  I don't know enough about JSON-WSP or JSPN Api to comment further.